# How to update MongoDB models in Prisma

Tags: next.js, prisma

I'm new to Prisma and I just updated some properties in my models. The problem is that when I try to create a new document in Prisma the new properties aren't recognised, but the older ones are. Here is my code as a reference (I'm using Next 13):

`prisma/prisma.schema`

```
datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Post {
  id     String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  title  String
  userId String @db.ObjectId
  user   User   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
}

model User {
  id    String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  email String
  posts Post[]
}
```

`app/page.tsx`

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

async function createUser() {
  const res = await prisma.user.create({
    data: {
      email: "helloPrisma@email.com",
      posts: {
        create: {
          title: 'My first post',
        }
      }
    }
  });

  return res;
}

export default async function Home() {
  const user = await createUser();
  
  return (
    <main>
      <pre>
        { JSON.stringify(user, null, 2) }
      </pre>
    </main>
  )
}
```

I also tried running `npx prisma generate` but it resulted in an error. Note: When I go into the Prisma Studio the data seems to have the updated properties

Comment: what the error details you get when you run npx prisma generate

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this command

```
npx prisma db push
```

Comment: Your answer could do with supporting evidence. Please consider [editting](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77573006/edit) your answer and including context and links for further reading.